# Meaning of flow rate in water pump

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Rated flow in the following is in conjunction with the rated lift meaning it can lift 15 meters at flow of 12 Liter/ minutes from a well? But what if its sucking water from the water company with existing flow rate. So the total flow rate is additive and is more than 12L/ minute, right?  Or wrong? I plan to buy this pump and it confused me for days.

[image]

Comment: No pump can suck water up more than about 10 meters. You can push water up 15 meters.

Comment: If it cant suck 10 meters. Why is there a max lift of 20 meters and rated lift of 15 meters.

Comment: You can lift by pushing or pulling. A pump can’t suck any lower than a perfect vacuum which will lift water only about 10 meters.

Comment: What is the diameter of this 10 meters limit? Is it like 4inches or even say 1 meter diameter pipe or no limit and any diameter?

Comment: Diameter doesn’t matter. When sucking water up, you can’t create more than one atmosphere differential pressure.

Comment: Is the rated lift if 15 meters above the suction lift or the discharge lift?

Comment: Is the consequence of all this where suction side can only suck at 10 meters (corresponding to 14.2 psi) means all  pumps no matter how powerful can only suck 14.2 at the suction side while it can get say 10,000 psi on the discharge side??

Comment: That’s correct except the max for sucking is about 14.7 psi.

Answer (score 3):

To fully answer we need a diagram of how this pump will be connected to the water company. I will speculate on a few configurations:

If the city water flows into a bucket at atmospheric pressure, and the pump pulls out of that bucket, it will just be limited to the performance of the pump as expected.

If the city water flows into the inlet of this pump; the users (sprinklers etc) on the outlet will see an increase in pressure. (~15m of water more pressure for your 12L/m) This configuration is typically called a "boost pump", because it boosts the pressure.

Increased pressure can mean increased flow, but the amount the flow increases depends on the the downstream user. For a sprinkler or some sort of orifice type restriction, the [orifice equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orifice_plate#Incompressible_flow) gives us some idea. If the pressure at your sprinkler/user goes up by a factor of 4, the flow rate through that sprinkler/user will double.

Note that if the flow from the city water is higher than this 12L/m rating of the pump you will see less pressure boost, and at some point (say 24L/m) this pump will actually reduce the pressure (and the resultant flow) delivered.

Comment: Its the case where the city water flows into the inlet of the pump. Do you have more reference how the pump will actually reduce the pressure delivered and where is the threshold or boundary? I couldnt find this in internet search. What terms must i look for? Pump saturation? Thanks.

Comment: It will be related to the geometry internal to the pump; requiring experimentation. I can estimate it though. What flow do you want to achieve? (or back up and tell me what the user is, what the status is with the existing water, and what your end goal is).

Comment: My restroom entry valve water flow is also 12 L per minute (I measured with container) direct from water company. If i will put the 12 L per minute pump. How large can it boost it? Wont it be 12 + 12 = 24 L per minute from outlet of the pump? Lets not take any sprinklers into accountz just the pump outlet. Imagine its sucking 15 meters (of lift) of the water company pipeline. If its lower. I want to know how to calculate roughly the total flow.

Comment: A centrifugal pump can certainly suck (within the limits of atmospheric pressure /cavitation), but it certainly wont double your flow rate. Lets say your city water pressure is 72psig or 500kPa at zero flow. At the full 12L/min into the bucket it is at 0psig or 0kPa. So it is taking 72psi differential to push that water from the water company to your entry valve at 12L/min. 15m of water is 21psi or 145kPa, but on suction your are limited by cavitation (atmospheric pressure is the hard limit at 14.7psi), so lets say the pump will do 10psi/69kPa suction....

Comment: ...so with the pump in series you now have 72psi + 10psi or 82psi differential from the water company. (I'm going to back track on the equations because units in terms of absolute pressure probably matter and don't have time to get all that straight). If you instead just look at a linear increase (which it in fact will be less than this), you new flow would be flow= 82/72 * 12L/min = 13.7L/min

Comment: How did you compute 15m of water is 21psi? Also why is there cavitation in the impeller? The inlet is not closed or block so cant cause cavitation. Also the new flow being 13.7L/min is just very small increase to the water company 12 L/min, isnt it?

Comment: You cant push a rope. If the pressure of a water stream goes below atmospheric pressure, the water will become water vapor. It is called NPSH; temperature and elevation come into effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_positive_suction_head

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=15m+in+inches
https://www.google.com/searchq=590.551inches+water+in+psi

Comment: Tnx. Now with sprinklers or shower and all the smaller hose and couplings. I noticed the flow rate becomes just 3 Liter per minute out of shower head from 12 Liter per minute restroom entry pipe. Here it seems the booster pump can double the flow rate of the 3 liters per minute to 6 liters per minute. Any idea why?

Comment: In this case since you are pushing you get the full 21psi. Since you doubled the flow we know your pressure on the nozzles went up by a factor of 4. So P + 21psi = P * 4, so your pressure without the boost pump is 7psi, and your pressure with the boost pump is 28psi. (this is pretty sloppy since the pressure in you pump would be a bit higher at the lower flow, but you get the idea).

Comment: What you mean pushing? Pushing against the shower head? And why do you say i double the flow. You just described the flow is not 12l/min + 12l/min but only 13.7 L/m. If i use the shower. What is being doubled and why double? This is last questions. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry pushing was slang, just saying that you are not sucking or limited by atmospheric pressure / NPSH. When you said "it seems the booster pump can double the flow" I assumed you tested this scenario, so I extrapolated the data based on your 3 to 6 double information. This scenario is much more likely and viable so I went with it. So in that hypothetical scenario where your shower head is getting 7psi and 3L/min from the water company, this pump would boost the pressure up to 28psi and the flow out the shower heads would increase to 6L/min.

Comment: Just to clarify something. When you mentioned "Lets say your city water pressure is 72psig or 500kPa at zero flow. At the full 12L/min into the bucket it is at 0psig or 0kPa. So it is taking 72psi differential to push that water from the water company to your entry valve at 12L/min "..where did you get the 72psig figure. I saw 18 psi at my gauge at water entrance. So its really 18 psi and not 72psi? Or the psi in my house entrance is different to the psi in the water company? And you need to use the water company psi and not my house psi to add to psi of the pump of 10psi you mentioned? Tnx.

Comment: 72psi is just a number a made up. If you pressure gauge reads 18psi when there is zero flow that is the pressure at the water company (or there is a bad regulator between you and them). Using the boost pump on lower pressue will certainly make a bigger difference. 10psi of suction is also a number I made up. The pump may go higher and may also cavitate (which will reduce its life). If you plug 10psi into the ratio you get 28/18 * 12 L/min = 18.7L/min. But remember its closer to square root than linear so you will probably see something closer to 15L/min.